# hexadecimal string to wireshark pcap

Tags: linux, wireshark

I have a hex string which I want to convert into a Wireshark pcap. Wireshark accepts a hex dump in the following format:

```
0000 00 00 00 00 00 aa 00 00 00 00 00 01 88 47 00 3e
0010 80 0a 00 00 d1 0a 10 00 89 02 20 01 05 46 00 00
0020 00 01 00 02 04 03 6d 64 31 02 03 6d 61 57 00 00
0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0040 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0050 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0060 00 00 00 00 00
```

I have the following stream:

```
0000000000AA0000000000018847003E800A0000D10A100089022001054600000001000204036D643102036D615700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I have been experimenting with  `od -Ax -tc1 -v` command in linux but can not seem to get the correct output. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: the stream is in text format? in a file?

Comment: Yes its in a file which I pass to the od command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following script. This is just a workaround. `od` and `hexdump` will interpret `0` as the character `'0'`, and use the byte `48`, so you may not get proper output. The script reads two chars for 16 times, and offset is incremented accordingly. Pretty simple to understand I guess:)

```
#!/bin/bash
off=0
while [ 1 ]
do
        printf "%04x " $off
        for ((i=0;i<16;i++))
        do
                read -n 2 a
                [ $? -ne 0 ] && echo && exit
                echo -n "$a "
        done
        echo
        off=`expr $off + 16`
done <test
```

where `test` is the file that holds the stream. I got the following output for your input.

```
0000 00 00 00 00 00 AA 00 00 00 00 00 01 88 47 00 3E
0010 80 0A 00 00 D1 0A 10 00 89 02 20 01 05 46 00 00
0020 00 01 00 02 04 03 6D 64 31 02 03 6D 61 57 00 00
0030 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0040 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0050 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0060 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: I noticed that `od` was returning the hex value the character zero. Thanks for this script.

Answer (score 6):

First put the hex stream into a text file "a.txt",

```
0000000000AA0000000000018847003E800A0000D10A100089022001054600000001000204036D643102036D615700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

then convert the text file into a binary file:

```
xxd -r -p a.txt a.bin
```

using od and text2pcap to convert the binary file to a pcap file.

```
od -Ax -tx1 -v a.bin | text2pcap - a.pcap
```